# How to setup two PayPal Express Checkout in a store?

Tags: magento2, checkout, paypal, payment, paypal-express

If the product is below a specific price, then use `Paypal merchant account` **`A`**, use `PayPal merchant account` **`B`** otherwise.

Is it possible to configure like these in `Magento 2.x`?

Or **How could I achieve this use-case?**

Thanks a lot !